# selecting space in between Emails

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL I have a table called Associations where there is a column called Email

Emails are in format
abc@xyz.com

if I want to select all emails which have word webmaster I use query.

```
 select * from associations where email like '%webmaster%';
```

there are some emails which has space and are not in format abc.xyz.com

they are in format like
 @abc. xyxyz . com

how can i select all emails that have space in between them.

Comment: If `like '%webmaster%'` selects all emails with the word 'webmaster', then `like '% %'` might select all that have a space?

Comment: it does not select all the emails this way..I've tried that

Comment: Really? That's surprising. Either the space isn't a real space (maybe another character), or your query is wrong. Did you try to combine conditions? `where email like '%webmaster%' and email like '% %'` will select only emails that contain both 'webmaster' and a space. Use `or` instead of `and` to select either.

Comment: basically it selects emails that are in format like  " b abc.xyz.com" but emails with @abc. xyxyz . com are not included.

Comment: @mb1987 - The query Golez provided should work for those examples.  Have you considered that those gaps may be tabs/newlines?  Try checking `HEX(email)` to see what you're dealing with.

Comment: thanks for the reply i used replace function and got rid of all spaces. it worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `like`:

```
where email like '% %'
```

To get a lot of bad format emails, you could do:

```
where email like '% %' or
      email not like '%@%.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to find emails that have any sort of whitespace in them (e.g., spaces, tabs, etc.), then you might want to use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM associations
 WHERE email RLIKE '\s'
```

One caveat is that matching regular expressions is a heavy CPU operation.